# how to print variables after to use subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess

In my program, I use subprocess.call to run apache drill automatically.
After that, I make some queries and I would like to print the result.
Before to program the code to run apache drill automatically, I was doing it manually and i could print the results but now i cannot do it.
My last try was to write in a file, but the behavior is the same, nothing is written.
My code is bellow.

```
import subprocess
from pydrill.client import PyDrill
import sys
writer = open('resultado.txt', 'w')
cmdmsg = subprocess.check_output("cd C:\\Users\\Tito\\Downloads\\apache-drill-1.14.0\\bin & sqlline -u \"jdbc:drill:zk=local\"", shell = True)
writer.write("teste de msg: " + str(cmdmsg))
drill = PyDrill(host='localhost', port=8047)
if drill.is_active:
    result = drill.query('''SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json` LIMIT 3''')
    result2 = drill.query('''SELECT * FROM dfs.`/Users/Tito/Desktop/banco_gal.csv` LIMIT 5''')
    for tuple in result2:
        writer.write(tuple)
writer.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem.
3 things are important for this topic.
a) we should kill the java virtual machine and shell after that apache drill is turned on.
b) the windows buffer is very short, so the result has not been printed.
c) popen method is better than call for this task.

```
import os
import re
import subprocess
import traceback
from os import path
from pydrill.client import PyDrill

DRILL_HOST = 'localhost'
DRILL_PORT = 8047

JAVA_HOME = ''
JAVA_HOME = JAVA_HOME or ("JAVA_HOME" in os.environ and os.environ["JAVA_HOME"])


JPS_EXE_PATH = path.join(JAVA_HOME, 'bin', 'jps.exe')

KILL_DRILL_JVM = True

def getJvmPID(className):
    pid = None
    print('Running JPS cmd: %s' % JPS_EXE_PATH)
    jpsOutput = subprocess.check_output(JPS_EXE_PATH)
    jpsOutput = str(jpsOutput)
    se = re.search(r'([0-9]*\s*)' + className, jpsOutput)
    if se:
        pid = se.group(1)
    return pid

def killProcessByPID(pid):
    killCmd = ['taskkill', '/f', '/pid', str(pid)]
    print('Running taskkill cmd: %s' % killCmd)
    killCmdOuput = subprocess.check_output(killCmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(str(killCmdOuput))

def killJvm(className):
    pid = getJvmPID(className)
    killProcessByPID(pid)


drillBinDir    = 'C:/Users/Tito/Downloads/apache-drill-1.14.0/bin'

sqlinePath   = path.join(drillBinDir, 'sqlline.bat')

drillCmdList = [sqlinePath , '-u', '"jdbc:drill:zk=local"']
drillCmdStr = " ".join(drillCmdList)
drillConAttempts = 2
while drillConAttempts > 0:
        drillConAttempts -= 1
        print("Connecting to drill on %s:%d..." % (DRILL_HOST, DRILL_PORT))
        try:
            drill = PyDrill(host=DRILL_HOST, port=DRILL_PORT)
        except:
            print("Exception when creating object")
            traceback.print_exc()

        print("Checking Drill conection...")
        try:
            if drill.is_active():
                print("Connected.")
                break
            elif drillConAttempts > 0:
                print("Could not connect to Drill. Trying to start Drill...")
                print("Running cmd '%s > %s'" % (drillCmdStr, os.devnull) )
                devNull = open(os.devnull,"w")
                cmdProc = subprocess.Popen(drillCmdStr, cwd=drillBinDir, stdout=devNull, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
                print("Started CMD process with PID %d" %(cmdProc.pid))
        except:
            print("Exception when checking connection")
            traceback.print_exc()



if drill.is_active():
    result = drill.query('''SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json` LIMIT 3''')
    for resultTuple in result:
        print(resultTuple)

if KILL_DRILL_JVM:
    print('Killing Drill process...')
    killJvm('SqlLine')
```